# Difference Between Tile and Data usage & Feature Service

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-runtime

With Developer Account we get upto 5GB free for Tile And Data usage and uptoo 100 MB free for Feature Service. We are not sure what's the difference between two?

If I upload 100MB+ Geojson file will it be considered under 100MB or 5GB?

Thank you,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the data to ArcGIS, it will be published as a layer in a Feature Service. This will then count towards the 100MB Feature limit. However, feature service storage is typically (always?) more efficient than GeoJSON storage. For example, in a quick test, a 521KB GeoJSON file downloaded from [here](https://data.beta.nyc/dataset/nyc-school-districts) turned into [328KB Feature Service](https://arcg.is/1O4nfX). Geometries in feature services are stored as binary fields, and various other efficiencies of the backing hosted feature service (such as efficiently storing attribute data) will also help. There are of course many factors that influence this, but I expect you would always see an improvement over the raw GeoJSON size.

Note that the GeoJSON file you upload will also be stored as the source for the published feature service as part of your 5GB limit (this is so you can upload updated GeoJSON and republish your feature service at the same URL). You can delete this if you won't ever need to update the feature service this way. For reference, [here's the GeoJSON file](https://arcg.is/1XveDn1) I uploaded (it seems that was also compressed slightly for storage to 509KB).